# Get array object on checkbox ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I had this parent child component, its a list of checkbox. I would like to get all object that needs to be sent to the service. I tried to get it but still I get only one data object at a time.

Parent: UserTypePermissions
Child: UserTypeCard

```
export const UserTypePermission = (props: any) => {

  const { id } = props;
  const [check, setIsCheck] = useState([]);
  const getRoles = async() => {
      await asyncListRole(`permission/${id}`, "")
        .then((resp: any) => {
          setIsCheck(resp.data?.permissions)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      getRoles()
      
    }, [])

    const [change, onChange] = useState<any>({})
    console.log(...change, "*******")

    const handleSubmit = () => {
          sendData to server
}
    return (
        <>
            <PageTitle>Permission</PageTitle>
              <Typography className="sub-header mb-2 w-50 mt-4"><ArrowLeft cursor="pointer" />Edit Permission</Typography>
                {
                  check.map((
                    (ch: any, index: number) => <UserTypeCard ch={ch} key={index} {...props} onChange={onChange} /> 
                  ))
                }
                <Button
                size="large"
                className="mt-4"
                style={{ width: '6vw', padding: '6px' }}
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                onClick={handleSave}
                label="Save"
                icon={<Save />}
              />
            
        </>
    )
}
```

```
export const UserTypeCard = (props: any) => {

    const styles = useStyles(props);
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const { onChange } = props;
    const [checkbox, setCheckbox] = useState<IPermission>(
      {
        service: props.ch.service,
        read: Boolean(props.ch.read),
        create: Boolean(props.ch.create),
        update: Boolean(props.ch.update),
        delete: Boolean(props.ch.delete),
        export: Boolean(props.ch.export),
      })

    const checkboxFunction = (event: any, type: string) => {
      return (
        setCheckbox({...checkbox, [type]: !!event.target.checked, }),
        onChange({[type]: !!event.target.checked, ...checkbox})
        
      )
    }

    return (
        <>
        <Card style={{ marginBottom: '25px', width: '83vw' }} sx={{borderColor: "1px solid red"}} key={props.index}>
            <div onClick={() => setIsOpen(prev => !prev)}> 
                <CardContent className={styles.root} key={props.index}>
                <ChevronRight className={isOpen ? styles.reverseDropdownIcon : styles.dropdownIcon} />
                <Typography
                    className={styles.title}
                    variant="subtitle1"
                    component="span"
                >
                    { props.ch.service.toUpperCase().replace("_", " ").replace("-", " ") }
                </Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </div>
            <CardContent className={isOpen ? styles.content : styles.hidden}>

                {/* Read */}
                <div className={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <Typography
                    className={styles.title}
                    variant="subtitle1"
                    component="span"
                >
                    Read
                </Typography>
                <Checkbox
                    // checked={checkbox['read']}
                    className={styles.checkbox}
                    onChange={(e: any) => {checkboxFunction(e, 'read')}}
                />
                </div>

                {/* Create */}
                <div className={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <Typography
                    className={styles.title}
                    variant="subtitle1"
                    component="span"
                >
                    Create
                </Typography>
                <Checkbox
                    // checked={checkbox['create']}
                    className={styles.checkbox}
                    onChange={(e: any) => checkboxFunction(e, 'create')}
                />
                </div>

                {/* Update */}
                <div className={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <Typography
                    className={styles.title}
                    variant="subtitle1"
                    component="span"
                >
                    Update
                </Typography>
                <Checkbox
                    // checked={checkbox['update']}
                    className={styles.checkbox}
                    onChange={(e: any) => checkboxFunction(e, 'update')}
                />
                </div>

                {/* Delete */}
                <div className={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <Typography
                    className={styles.title}
                    variant="subtitle1"
                    component="span"
                >
                    Delete
                </Typography>
                <Checkbox
                    // checked={checkbox['delete']}
                    className={styles.checkbox}
                    onChange={(e: any) => checkboxFunction(e, 'delete')}
                />
                </div>

                {/* Delete */}
                <div className={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <Typography
                    className={styles.title}
                    variant="subtitle1"
                    component="span"
                >
                    Export
                </Typography>
                <Checkbox
                    // checked={checkbox['export']}
                    className={styles.checkbox}
                    onChange={(e: any) => checkboxFunction(e, 'export')}
                />
                </div>
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
        </>

    )
}
```

I would like to get the changes

IT Department

[/] create [/]update [/]delete [/] export

Accounting

[/] create [/]update [/]delete [/] export

when I check this I would like to transform them to payload like this

payload

```
{

  id: 1,
  permissions: [
   {department: 'it', create: 1, update: 1, delete: 0, export:0},
   {department: 'accounting', create: 1, update: 1, delete: 0, export:0}
  ]
}
```

but everytime I check the specific department the current department I check is only data I get, not the other department I modified. Hope someone could help me this.

Answer (score 0):

few pointers that could help

```
   // in child
   const checkboxFunction = (event: any, type: string) => {
      return (
        setCheckbox({...checkbox, [type]: !!event.target.checked, }),
        onChange({[type]: !!event.target.checked, ...checkbox})
        
      )
    }

  // use function updater and move this to parent

   onChange(state => {

       const mappedList = state?.map(item => {

          if (item.id === id) {
              // this is the item you need to update
              // set the structure according to your needs
              return  {
                 ...item,
                 ...checkbox
                 [type]: !!event.target.checked,
              }

          } else {
             return item;
          }

       }
      
       return mappedList;

   })
```

checkout the new docs on how to [update arrays in React](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#replacing-items-in-an-array), the will help a lot

I deally you should move the state to the parent and pass a updater function to the child, which just takes the parent id,
so that you dont have to keep parent and child states in sync, which could lead to errors with [duplicate states](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#replacing-items-in-an-array)

and  in parent

```
   useEffect(() => {

      // or consider moving the function inside the hook

      getRoles(id)
      
   }, [id])  // include props, state in dependency array
```

Hope it helps and I encourage you to read the new [React documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn)